# How to install Tntcontrols in Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am new to Delphi, I need TntContols package in my project, Download TntContols in https://github.com/pitfiend/TntControls, the install `TntUnicode-master\Delphi\d7TntUnicodeVcl_D70.dpk`, then I drag a TntButton into the form, and Run my application, but error throw:

```
[Fatal Error] Unit1.pas(7): File not found: 'TntStdCtrls.dcu'
```

code below:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, TntStdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TTntButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the path where TntStdCtrls.dcu is located to your project's search path?

Comment: You need to add the \Source directory to your library path. And remember that you have two dpk files, you have to build both and install the design-time one : TntUnicodeVcl_D70.dpk

Comment: @MarcGuillot Is the two packages are `TntUnicodeVcl_R70.dpk` and `TntUnicodeVcl_D70.dpk`? And what's the deferent about the two packages?

Comment: @TangMonk The R70 is the run-time package, it has the code that executes your application at run-time, while the D70 is the design-time package, it has the code that executes the IDE at design time (so this one needs to be installed on the IDE). So this way the component can have slightly different code inside the IDE than on the EXE file (all the customization panels on the IDE doesn't need to be on the EXE).

Comment: Hi @MarcGuillot: Not meaning to argue but the statement "it has the code that executes your application at run-time" is possibly misleading.  It's certainly true if the application is compiled to use runtime packages, but I don't believe the runtime package's BPL is involved if the compiler is compiling a stand-alone EXE, because the necessary code is linked from the corresponding DCUs, not the BPL.

Comment: Yes, I intended to mean that that package contains the code that goes linked in your executable, so it's the code executed by your application at run time (but not necessarily in the form of a BPL). Thanks @MartynA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the BPL and DCU files that come with D7 are installed in the .LIB and .BIN folders, respectively, below the main Delphi folder, which I'll refer to as \D7.

It's best not to install other components to those folders.  The reason is that eventually, as you install extra 3rd party libraries, you are likely to run into a compilation error "Unit Y was compiled with a different version of unit Y" which may require you to re-install Delphi if files in the BIN and LIB folders are involved.  Actually, this problem usually arises after you've compiled a project which is configured so that it needlessly has access to the library's .PAS files (because the IDE does not need access to the libary's .PAS during compilation of a project which uses the library, as long as it can find the library's .DCU files).

Many 3rd party libraries include (at least) two .DPK files, one of which is a so-called runtime package and the other is a design-time package.  The design-time package is the one you install in the IDE to install the library's components and the run-time package contains routines which those in the design-time package depend on.  Unless a project which uses the libary is compiled to use runtime packages, the runtime package is not used in the process of compiling the project (but the counterpart .DCU files will be, which is why the IDE needs to be configured to find them).

What I've always done for 3rd party D7 libraries which don't have their own installer is as follows:

1. One-time only:  Create a folder \D7\LIB2.  Add it to your OS Path.
2. For each .DPK file in the library you wish to install:

   a.  Open the .DPK file in the IDE and edit its BPL and DCU output folders to \D7\LIB2. Do this by clicking the `Options` button in the Package editor and in the Project Options pop-up, on the `Directories/Conditionals` tab, set the Output Directory, Units Output Directory and DCP Output Directory all to `\D7\LIB2`

   b.  Compile the package by clicking the `Compile` button, then install it in the IDE by clicking the `Install` button if it's enabled.

   c.  Close the Package (.DPK) editor.
3. Open your project which is to use the library and edit its search path to include \D7\LIB2 but NOT the path to the library's .PAS files.
4. Compile your project.

Notes:

Notice that the abouve does NOT include adding the path to the source (.PAS files) of the library to your project.  Doing so is unnecessary if you follow the above steps and only likely to lead (eventually) to the occurrence of the "Unit Y was compiled ..." error I mentioned.

The above method also works with recent Delphi versions, though involves more clicking around to do the necessary since the stand-alone .DPK editor was removed from the IDE.

Comment: Where is the configuration of BPL and DCU output folders in D7

Comment: See the update to my answer.  The BPL configuration is set in step 2 a., and the DCUs (for projects which use the library) in step 3

Comment: I also have installed [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en), a Delphi 7 auto-completion plugin, CnPack donot know there a another LIB2 should to be auto-completion, Do you know how to set CnPack to search in D7/LIB2?